# How to make input string value to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a `jquery` variable like this :

```
var d1 = [{text:'t1',value:'1'},{text:'t2',value:'2'},{text:'t3',value:'3'},{text:'t4',value:'4'}];
console.log(d1);
```

When i display it in `console.log`, i have something similar to the image below

[image]

Now if i had an input in html like this :

```
<input id="txtstr" name="txtstr" value="[{text:'t1',value:'1'},{text:'t2',value:'2'}, {text:'t3',value:'3'},{text:'t4',value:'4'}]" type="text" />
```

in `console.log` i have :

```
console.log($("#txtstr").val());
```

[image]

I want to have json array in `console.log` when i use `input` (Like the first picture). I have also used `json.parse` but it didn't work.

Comment: JSON is *always* `{ "key": "value" }` never `: 'value'`.   `.val()` will give you a string (JSON), you need to parse that to get an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the attribute value isn't having a value quoted, you don't put `text` and `value` in quotes. to fix this do the following

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtstr" name="txtstr" value='[{"text":"t1","value":"1"},{"text":"t2","value":"2"},{"text":"t3","value":"3"},{"text":"t4","value":"4"}]' type="text" />
<script>
    var inputString = $("#txtstr").val();
    var jsonArray = JSON.parse(inputString);
    console.log(jsonArray);
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer does not work

Comment: It works well, i tried it twice

Comment: If you execute it here, it is because your code is jQuery

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, I wrote a mistake in putting single quotation and double quotation. It works now

Answer (score 0):

It is because your input value does not follow the standard JSON format, where keys and string values are enclosed in double quotes.
It shoutld be

```
<input id="txtstr" name="txtstr" value='[{"text":"t1","value":"1"},{"text":"t2","value":"2"},{"text":"t3","value":"3"},{"text":"t4","value":"4"}]' type="text" />
```

and your code will work fine

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = $.trim($('#txtstr').val());

//adding double quotes to keys and values
string = string.replace(/([{,])(\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)\s*:/g, '$1"$3":');
string = string.replace(/:\s*'([^']+?)'/g, ':"$1"');

//string to a JSON object
var obj = JSON.parse(string);

console.log(obj);
console.log(typeof(obj));
console.log(obj[1].value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtstr" name="txtstr" value="[{text:'t1',value:'1'},{text:'t2',value:'2'}, {text:'t3',value:'3'},{text:'t4',value:'4'}]" type="text" />
```